# How to move Mock classes from src to test package and load them as beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, junit5

I am assigned to upgrade a project(not done by me or anyone I can contact) and one task is to move the test specific mock classes to the test package. I am including parts of the code that you guys may find useful to help me. I am only learning with junit.

Edit: *We already have integration and unit tests inside the test package, it's all working fine. But the mock classes(3 of them) and the mock server that are required when running these test cases are written inside the source package and are currently initiated as a bean inside the main class. Is there a way to move these mock classes and mock server to the test package and start them as a bean when executing the test classes?*

This is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package.name", entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstFactory", transactionManagerRef = "firstTXManager")
@EnableIntegration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ...
        ...
        SpringApplication.run(Driver.class, args);
    }
    ...
    ...

    //I need to move the following code, but I don't know to where!
    @Bean
    @Profile({ "test" })
    public Mockers mockersTest() {
        return new Mockers();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile({ "mock1", "mock2" })
    public MockersDev mockersDev() {
        return new MockersDev();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile({ "online1", "online2", "online3", "staging" })
    public MockersProd mockersProd() {
        return new MockersProd();
    }
}
```

Mock server class. I tried moving this mock server and the next three mock classes to test package. But I don't know how to initialize them, as done within the main class.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Queues;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;
import org.jboss.netty.logging.InternalLoggerFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@ConditionalOnProperty(name = { "app.server.enabled" }, matchIfMissing = true)
@Configuration
public class MockServer {
    ...
    ...
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mockServerQueue")
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> mockServerQueue;

    @Bean
    public LinkedBlockingQueue<String> mockServerQueue() {
    return Queues.newLinkedBlockingQueue(100);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> startServer() throws Exception {
        return new ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>() {
            public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
                ...

            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> stopServer() throws Exception {
        return new ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>() {
            public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
                ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Following are the three Mock classes

```
import de.svenjacobs.loremipsum.LoremIpsum;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public class Mockers
implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    ...
    ...    
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...//serveral other methods
    ...
}
```

```
import de.svenjacobs.loremipsum.LoremIpsum;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; // Added missing imports.
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import au.com.streamlinemedia.abc.service.HttpService;

@Transactional
public class MockersDev implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    ...
    ...
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
    ...//serveral other methods
    ...
}
```

```
import de.svenjacobs.loremipsum.LoremIpsum;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public class MockersProd implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    ...
    ...
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    //Empty method
    }
    ...//serveral other methods
    ...
}
```

Comment: have you tried simply moving bean definitions such as ` @Bean public Mockers mockersTest() { ... ) `  to some configuration file in the src/test package?

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir I had asked the same on reddit and got a hint from there and its fixed. https://www.reddit.com/r/SpringBoot/comments/12qdfm6/how_to_move_mock_classes_from_src_to_test_package/